# TFS204018 error when installing NuGet Package in VS2015

Tags: tfs, nuget, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I install a NuGet package in a TFS source-controlled VS 2015 project, I get a message similar to the following output under "Source Control - Team Foundation":

> TF204018: Could not check the file's encoding because the file C:\TFS\Oz.Interfaces\Main\Source\MVRSTamperCodes\MVRSTamperCodes.Web\web.config is in use.

I've been searching fruitlessly to see if there's a way to fix this issue and haven't found anything yet. Does anyone know what is causing this message and/or what steps I can take to fix it? I should note that this doesn't prevent the successful installation of the NuGet package so it appears to just be a warning or informational message.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've met similar issue with blocking web.config and other files. My solution was:

1. Uninstall NuGet Package Manager (**Tools -> Extensions and Updates**)
2. Install newest version (currently: **Nuget 3.2**)

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue for me as well (although I was already at a 3.2 version, but there was still another upgrade available). Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Upgrading Nuget from `3.0.60624.657` to `3.2.60914.10516` fixed it - no need to uninstall. Warnings still appear in the TFS output window, but no errors. Was throwing "object reference" error when installing **application insights**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Team Foundation Server, you will need to first check out the entire project, before updating Nuget Packages for the project, if you have this problem.